# Design parent-child controllers

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am new to cakePHP and trying to get my head around the framework to see how to implement my requirements.

My application allows (admin) users to define Forms (parent) and FormElements (child) that later on will be composed on the fly and presented to the end-users.

To start prototyping I baked all the pieces and I can enter rows in both tables as expected.

edit to simplify the question:

The Forms controller already shows a list of Forms and when one is selected (view action), a list of the FormElements for that Form.
But... when I add a new FormElement, I have to select again a Form the Element will be associated to.

Instead I want the FormElements controller/model to know which Form was initially selected and fill the form_id automagically.

Is there a "best practice" approach on how to handle this ?

Just in case its needed:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `form_elements` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `form_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `widget` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mandatory` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I've made some progress by looking around how sample projects do this. I am currently using URLs such as:
<parent_name>/<parent_id>/<child_controller>/<action>/<id>
and I use parent name and id as needed to build links between the 2 controllers and database updates.

Comment: Not exactly "elegant" and lots of fiddly work.
In any case... is there anyone out there willing to shed some light?

Comment: you are misusing some terms and it is making your question a bit confusing. What do you mean by a child controller id? Are you referring to the model id?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will review the question and try to explain myself better.

Comment: @AngelS.Moreno: BTW, yes, I meant the id of the model/table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens more often than you think. I had QuestionModel hasMany AnswerModel and wanted to add Answers within my AnswersController. I needed to show QuestionModel name and other attributes of the "parent" object. This is what my add action inside my AnswersController looks like:

```
public function add($question_id = null) {
    $this->Answer->Question->id = $question_id;
    if (!$this->Answer->Question->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid question'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['Answer']['question_id'] = $question_id;
        $this->request->data['Answer']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

        if ($this->Answer->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlashSuccess(__('Your answer has been saved'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlashError(__('Your answer could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'questions','action' => 'view', $question_id));
    }

    $question = $this->Answer->Question->read();
    $this->set('question', $question);
}
```

You will notice that I am passing the Question.id to the AnswersController add action. Having this allows me to pull the Question from the DB and allows me to be able to redirect the user back to the specific question they were on before they clicked on "Add Answers to this Question".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It seems to confirm my approach is, if not "generalized, at least intuitive.

Comment: I am aware this scenario is very common. I asked the question precisely to understand whether there is a common solution/approach.
I assume you have some routing that makes the question_id available to the Answers controller.
I am attempting to develop some basic utility methods that return, as an example, the URL to the parent etc...

Comment: IT is my experience that the example I provided is the common approach. I do not make use of routing for my solution. I construct a link like so: $this->Html->link('Add a possible answer', array('controller' => 'answers','action'=>'add',$question_id); this simply creates a url like so: http://mysite/answers/add/23 by default the "23" is passed to the AnswersController's add action as the first parameter of the function.

Comment: Furthermore, since Question hasMany Answer, after the redirect in the AnswersController to the QuestionsController, the answer just added is part of the Question array. The URL you want to pass back to the "parent", is this already in the ChildModel? Also, does your ChildModel have a proper relationship with the ParentModel? If both are true then you do not need to "pass" anything from the ChildController to the ParentController. Your ParentModel array will already have that data :-) GL!

Comment: After being busy with other things, I've put into pratice your suggestion and I wanted to thank you again.
Somehow I missed the fact that the only time when the parent id is needed is in the add action and that's exactly when there's no child id in the URL.